# mutate several columns from a dataframe based on a mapping between values from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes:

`df` looks like this

```
id   v1   v2   v3    v4   etc.
1    1     4    2     5
2    4     4    6     1
3    2     1    3     4
etc.
```

while `rules` looks like this

```
id       name
1        red
2        blue  
3        grey 
4        green  
5        black  
6        gold 
etc
```

what i want to obtain is the following

```
id        v1        v2        v3         v4   etc.
1         red       green     blue       black
2         green     green     gold       red
3         blue      red       grey       green
etc.
```

so basically using the map between number and colours in rules to mutate df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
results = df.applymap(lambda i: rules.loc[i, 'name'])
```

With `df` like

```
    v1  v2  v3  v4
id                
1    1   4   2   5
2    4   4   6   1
3    2   1   3   4
```

and `rules` like

```
     name
id       
1     red
2    blue
3    grey
4   green
5   black
6    gold
```

the result is

```
       v1     v2    v3     v4
id                           
1     red  green  blue  black
2   green  green  gold    red
3    blue    red  grey  green
```